# Jest Assert Promise Recursion

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have this async function to retry a promise following certain conditions.

```
async function retry(f, interval = 1000, retries = 10) {
try {
  return await f
} catch (e) {
  if (retries == 0) {
    throw e
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    retry(f, Math.min(60000, interval * 2), retries - 1);
  }, interval);
}
```

}

I would like to assert, using jest, the number of times the recursion was performed until the function had been thrown. This is the function call.

```
const f = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('test'))

retry(f)
```

Comment: You will probably need to use fakeTimers for this test https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html

Comment: Tried that, but did not work the way I tried. Appreciate any code demonstrating how to.

Comment: You cannot retry a promise, it resolves only once. You need to use a function that you can call multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` should be a function that you can call when you retry it. A `Promise` will only resolve/reject once and then stays in that state. Using a function will let you redo the thing you wanted to try.

When `f` is a function, it can itself be a closure counting the amount of times it was called. For example:

```
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, t);
  });
}
async function retry(f, interval = 100, retries = 10) {
  try {
    return await f();
  } catch (e) {
    if (retries == 0) {
      throw e;
    }
    await delay(interval);
    return retry(f, Math.min(60000, interval * 2), retries - 1);
  }
}

describe("retry", () => {
  it("retries 10 times", async () => {
    let count = 0;
    const f = () => {
      count++;
      return Promise.reject(`test ${count}`);
    };

    try {
      await retry(f);
    } catch (e) {
      // expect the last exception to be thrown
      expect(e).toEqual("test 11");
    }
    // 10 retries + first try = 11
    expect(count).toBe(11);
  });
});
```

Comment: @AndreFagundes Works just fine for me. Did you fix the `retry` function to *call* `f()`?